# Integral of a vector field

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to calculate the integral of the vector field $F(x,y,z)=(0,y^2,z)$ along the curve $r(t)=(\sin \pi t, \cos \pi t, t)$, $t\in [0,1]$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

$$F(r(t))=(0, \cos^2 \pi t, t) \\ r'(t)=(\pi \cos \pi t, -\pi \sin \pi t, 1)$$

Therefore, $$F(r(t))\cdot r'(t)=-\pi \sin \pi t\cdot \cos^2 \pi t+t$$

So, $$\int_r F(r)\cdot r' ds=\int_0^1 (-\pi \sin \pi t\cdot \cos^2 \pi t+t)dt=-\frac{1}{6}$$

$$$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I haven't done the integral, but it looks fine.

Comment: Ok... Thanks a lot!! :-) @Mattos